# About convert object to string

Tags: c#, .net

I test something about convert object to string on **C#.Net** . See this below !

```cs
    private static void stringCast(object obj)
    {
        string StringResult;

        #region " obj.ToString() "
        try
        {
            StringResult = obj.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("obj.ToString() Successed ");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("obj.ToString() Failed ");
        }
        #endregion

        #region " Convert.ToString(obj) "
        try
        {
            StringResult = Convert.ToString(obj);
            Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToString(obj) Successed ");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToString(obj) Failed ");
        }
        #endregion

        #region " (string)obj "
        try
        {
            StringResult = (string)obj;
            Console.WriteLine("(string)obj Successed ");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(string)obj Failed ");
        }
        #endregion

        #region " obj as string "
        try
        {
            StringResult = obj as string;
            Console.WriteLine("obj as string Successed ");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("obj as string Failed ");
        }
        #endregion
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            object ExecuteScalarResult;

            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(" obj is \"TEST\" ");

            ExecuteScalarResult = "TEST";

            stringCast(ExecuteScalarResult);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(" obj is number ");

            ExecuteScalarResult = 0123;

            stringCast(ExecuteScalarResult);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(" obj is null ");

            ExecuteScalarResult = null;

            stringCast(ExecuteScalarResult);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(" obj is DBNull ");

            ExecuteScalarResult = DBNull.Value;

            stringCast(ExecuteScalarResult);

        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.Write(" Please any key to exit. ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

[image]

> ### obj is `"TEST"` (string Type)
>
> `obj.ToString()` Successed 
>   `Convert.ToString(obj)` Successed 
>   `(string)obj` Successed 
>   `obj as string` Successed
>
> ### obj is `0123` (Numeric Type)
>
> `obj.ToString()` Successed 
>   `Convert.ToString(obj)` Successed 
>   `(string)obj` **Failed**
>   `obj as string` Successed
>
> ### obj is `null` (null Type)
>
> `obj.ToString()` **Failed**
>   `Convert.ToString(obj)` Successed 
>   `(string)obj` Successed 
>   `obj as string` Successed
>
> ### obj is `DBNull` (Class Type) *[new object() is same]*
>
> `obj.ToString()` Successed 
>   `Convert.ToString(obj)` Successed 
>   `(string)obj` **Failed**
>   `obj as string` Successed

I need more some information. Can someone explain please ?

Comment: Whats your problem? Actually it's super obvious what happend there

Comment: Please do not use keywords like C# etc in your titles. You already defined a tag, thats enough :)

Comment: I don't understand. Why Convert.ToString() can convert all type but another can't ?

Comment: You have used different types of objects and checked how its conversion or type casting works with various methods provided by c#. The results you have got are self explanatory. Can you please tell more about what exact information you are expecting?

Comment: you need to why some of the cases fail. right?

Comment: @madmax Yes alright, may be !

Comment: You should also try the case `ExecuteScalarResult = new object();`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's result is same DBNull. I think both is a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (string)obj Failed

This is because there is no type conversion defined from Integer to String. So you have to use the `ToString()` method for that. Similarly for DBNull to string.

> obj.ToString() Failed

You cannot call an instance method `ToString()` on a  null reference. You need a valid object to call the `ToString()` method.

Check out the following link regarding the `as` keyword:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: I accepted this answer because you are really knows.

Answer (score 4):

Ever learned the language in a structured way?

Here we go:

ToString is an INSTANCE method. It needs an object. Read up the difference between refernce and value types. Which is why it will not work on null - which is a null reference. Convert.ToString does work because it is a static method on the convert class - and particularly done for this case.

As string checks whether the object is of type string. NO conversion happens. Whih means as DbNull and "number" (whatever you put in there) fail because those are not strings. You can convert them - but AS is there to check without conversion (mostly used to check whether a class implements a specific interface).

Comment: But `as` should not throw an exception, so it should not have written "Failed" in that case. The `as` expression is just `null` in cases where the conversion is not possible.

Comment: Actually no. Which is why I commented the poster obviously never learned the language. AS returns NULL of the object is not of the defined type. Which is the advantage compared to cast. var x = m as string. if x != null... no exception handling needed.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for explain (and preach).

Comment: @TomTom as on DbNull doesn't fail. OP mistyped it.

Comment: @TomTom because it returns null instead of raising an exception if the conversion isn't possible.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right. See the updated question. That was a typo error.

Comment: Yes. My bad. DbNull is an object actually.